# How to Insert Into Table Values combining arguments and temp table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, temp-tables

I have INSERT statement where I have to use one of my argument values and values from my temporary table. I'm using SQL Server 2008. I haven't worked with temp tables before so I'm not sure if and how I can combine argument values and temp table since arguments have to be placed inside of the VALUES() and temp table values are pulled using SELECT. Here is my code:

```
INSERT INTO myTbl (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6)
//col1 should use #arguments.myVal# 
SELECT @col2,@col3,@col4,@col5,@col6
FROM #myTemp
```

Is there any way to combine values from two different sources into insert statement?

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  I can't figure out why you would try to fetch six constant values per row in `#myTemp`.

Comment: I'm taking values from temp table and inserting in different table but first column should get the value from the argument not from temp table.

Answer (score 0):

hope this what you are looking for.

```
Declare @Param1 int = 20

INSERT INTO myTbl (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6)
  SELECT @Param1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6
  FROM #myTemp
```